# rubycas-server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ldap, rubycas

This is the data that I get back from the rubycas server.

```
{
  "cn"=>"--- - Toby Joiner", 
  "sn"=>"--- - Joiner", 
  "mail"=>"--- - tobyjoiner@xxxxxx.xxx", 
  "memberof"=>"--- 
      - CN=All Users,OU=AllUsers,DC=bnw,DC=local
      - CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=bnw,DC=local 
      - CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=bnw,DC=local", 
  "givenname"=>"--- - Toby"
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way I am supposed pull this data out, right now I am doing:

```
first_name = session[:cas_extra_attributes][:sn].gsub('-','')
```

to remove the dashes.  I am hoping I am just missing the built in way to get the extra data out from the rubycas server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like YAML escaped data. You should be able to get rid of it by first parsing it through `YAML.load` and then processing it as you wish.

---

As a small aside, I've personally re-implemented the basic functions of rubycas-server as a Rails engine called [cassy](https://github.com/reInteractive/cassy). However, I don't think it supports sending through extra attributes at the moment.

I just thought I'd mention it as it gives you an alternative to try if rubycas-server doesn't work out.

Comment: Thank you.  The issue now is the rubycas-client overflowing the cookie buffer, which I fixed by changing the sessions to activerecord, but then it mangles the yaml.  Oh well, your answer is the right one for what I asked.